# Best way to set up dependent picklists in Lightning

Tags: bestpractice, lightning-aura-components

One common programming challenge I anticipate in Lightning is the need to set up dependent picklists. I've cobbled together [one approach shown in this gist](https://gist.github.com/martyychang/af8aa7705da69d23598e) for setting up a dependent picklist, but I feel like there must be a simpler or more reusable approach that I haven't uncovered yet. What other patterns or options are there for setting up a dependent picklist? Is there a best practice?