# How to create pick list of state and country in Lightning component?

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

I am making an component in lightning. i want to know how can we use the state and county picklist in this particular code.  secoundly the functionality of save and cancel button is also not working in the lightning component.Help me out.
 Thanx

```
<div class="container">                
    <form class="formbusiness">
        <h1>Account Information</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="headingB">Business Account Info</h1>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_cname" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.Name}" placeholder="Company Name" required="true"/>
                <ui:inputNumber aura:id="b_bphone" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.Phone}" placeholder="Phone" required="true"/>
                <ui:inputEmail aura:id="b_bemail" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.Email__c}" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_bstreet" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.BillingStreet}" placeholder="Billing Street"/>
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_bcity" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.BillingCity}" placeholder="Billing City"/>
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_state" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.BillingStateCode}" placeholder="State"/>
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_country" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.BillingCountryCode}" placeholder="Country"/>
                <ui:inputNumber aura:id="b_zipcode" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.BillingPostalCode}" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="headingB">Respective Contact</h1>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_rcfirstname" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBRCAccount.FirstName}" placeholder="First Name"/>
                <ui:inputText aura:id="b_rclastname" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBRCAccount.LastName}" placeholder="Last Name" required="true"/>
                <ui:inputNumber aura:id="b_rcmobile" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBRCAccount.MobilePhone}" placeholder="Mobile" required="ture"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ui:inputEmail aura:id="b_rcemail" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBRCAccount.Email}" placeholder="Email"/>
                <ui:inputNumber aura:id="b_rcphone" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBRCAccount.Phone}" placeholder="Phone"/>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonB">
            <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.createBAccount}"/>
            <ui:button label="Cancel"/>
        </div>        
    </form>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide some additional details about the controller(s), the JS code, etc.? How are you defining and loading the data, where are the picklists coming from, etc.? To construct a picklist in Winter '15 you will need to use a **select** and populate the **option** elements, then handle the change event to update the values. What is happening when you call the Action to create the record when the save button is pressed?

In the Spring '15 release you will find that the **force:recordEdit** and **force:recordView** components make this type of app much easier.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on the roadmap (I can create an idea if not), but it would be awesome if a developer in Lightning can do what's currently possible in Visualforce: Put `<apex:inputField value="{!Lead.StateCode}"/>` and `<apex:inputField value="{!Lead.CountryCode}"/>` on the same page, and have the picklists and their dependencies be automatically rendered.

Comment: @MartyC. can we use apex in the lightning ??  i have used it but nothing is happening ..  i am trying to  use a picklist in the lightning component instead  of this -<ui:inputText aura:id="b_country" class="form-control" value="{!v.newBAccount.BillingCountryCode}" placeholder="Country"/>

Comment: Yes, you can use Apex with Lightning. Take a look at the gist mentioned in this question I posted a while back: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55197/best-way-to-set-up-dependent-picklists-in-lightning

Comment: @MartyC. Thank you so much .. Really Worth for me..  Now understand the use of this .